# FFMPEG: Is it possible to get coded_width in new API?

Tags: ffmpeg, libavcodec, libav, libavformat

Consider following code (without initialization for brevity).

```
AVFormatContext *formatCtx;
int coded_width = formatCtx->streams[videoStreamIndex]->codec->coded_width;
```

In old API it was possible to get `coded_width` and `coded_height` this way. Currently it is deprecated. There is `AVCodecParameters`struct but it provides only:

```
int width
int height
```

which may be different from

```
int coded_width
int coded_height
```

So, is it possible to get coded_width without using deprecated `streams[videoStreamIndex]->codec`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My apologies for the late response. According to the response of @the kamilz [FFMPEG: Is it possible to get coded_width in new API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48794431/ffmpeg-is-it-possible-to-get-coded-width-in-new-api#comment84662115_48821665) the best solution seems to just suppress this warning in the header file. (I' m using gcc compiler).

> #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"

Answer (score 0):

For getting coded_width and coded_height You can use `ffprobe` also, if you run :

```
ffprobe -show_streams -i video.mp4
```

you will get a stream object which include coded_width & coded_height  :

```
index=0
codec_name=h264
codec_long_name=H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10
profile=High
codec_type=video
codec_time_base=9772827/468627200
codec_tag_string=avc1
codec_tag=0x31637661
width=1280
height=720
coded_width=1280
coded_height=720
has_b_frames=2
```

Comment: The question is about *API usage*, not command-line. Under the hood `ffprobe` shows  the values from the deprecated structure. This is exactly what the asker is trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

According to latest doxygen documentation, these are still valid and currently used in ffmpeg:

Declaration (w/o `deprecated` pragma):
https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/structAVCodecContext.html#ae3c157e97ff15d46e898a538c6bc7f09

Used in:
https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/qsvdec_8c-example.html#a21

Hope that helps.

Comment: Code:`formatCtx->streams[videoStreamIndex]->codec->coded_width`, types: `AVFormatContext->AVStream->AVCodecContext->int`. I can declare or use `AVCodecContext` struct and so on without warnings. But using `formatCtx->streams[videoStreamIndex]->codec` invokes warning. So generally it is possible to use `AVCodecContext` struct without any problems but it's not recommended to get info from this struct from AVStream. Take a look at https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.0/structAVStream.html and https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.3/structAVStream.html. `AVCodecContext *codec` doesn't exist in new one doc.

Comment: I think you should use pragmas to suppress Deprecation warnings as an exception for this case, I just examined ffmpeg source code (github) with keyword `coded_width`. Usign as you do, seems pretty much legit, at least as for latest version.